# jQuery play specific HTML5 video

Tags: jquery

I currently have a site setup with similar divs as to the one below. Only one is visible at a time.

```
<div id="intro_page" class="sub_page">

        <div class="sub_header"><img src="assets/img/intro_header.jpg" /></div>

        <div class="video_holder">
        <div class="play_button"></div>
            <video class="video_player" autobuffer>
                <source type="video/ogg" src="assets/media/test_video.ogg">
            </video>
        </div>

        <div class="page_text"><img src="assets/img/intro_text.jpg" width="1020" /></div>


    </div><!-- /intro_page -->
```

Each page has a similar `video_holder` div and I'm trying to play the video in that current div.

I've tried things similar to this, but with no luck.

```
$(".play_button").click(function() {

    $(this).fadeOut("slow");

    $(".video_player:visible").play();

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059640/use-jquery-to-control-video-tag

Comment: `$(".video_player:visible")[0].play();` should work

Comment: @Ohad, I realize that would work. But if I have 5 div's with all of them having similar .video_player tags, how can I specify that specific video, without having to do [0], [1], [2], etc. /Edit: Seems like that will work for the other div's as well. Since I am targeting the visible element. Thanks

Comment: Then you have to give unique ids to each of video elements, and store them in an array. Then you can access whichever you want using that collection.